# Dont know what to do these exception in thread main :(

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at Account.getBalance(Account.java:51)
        at Account.main(Account.java:95)
```

Here is the full code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Account
{
ArrayList<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> Cnic = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> Age = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Double> Balance = new ArrayList<Double>();

double amount;

/*Setting values */
public void setName(String name1)//Name
{
    Name.add(name1);
}
public void setCnic(String cnic1)//Cnic
{
    Cnic.add(cnic1);
}
public void setAge(int age1)//Age
{
    Age.add(age1);
}
public void setBalance(double bal)//Balance
{
    Balance.add(bal);
}
public void setSpecificBalance(int num, double bal)
{
    Balance.add(num,bal);
}
/*End of set methods */

/*Getting Values */
public String getName(int num)//Name
{
    return Name.get(num);
}
public String getCnic(int num)//Cnic
{
    return Cnic.get(num);
}
public int getAge(int num)//Age
{
    return Age.get(num);
}
public double getBalance(int num)//Balance
{
    return Balance.get(num);
}

public void printAccountsTill(int num)//Printing all accounts till a specified number
{
    for(int x=0; x<num; x++)
    {
        System.out.printf("\nName of Customer is: %s\n",Name.get(x));
        System.out.printf("\nCnic of Customer is: %S\n",Cnic.get(x));
        System.out.printf("\nAge of Custmoer is: %d\n",Age.get(x));
        System.out.printf("\nBalance is : %lf\n\n",Balance.get(x));
    }
}
/*End of get methods */

/*Start of Main Method */
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    Scanner inputI = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inputL = new Scanner(System.in);

    Account cust = new Account();

    String name,cnic;
    int age,temp=1,temp1=0,temp2,check;
    int numb, dep, with;

    while(temp!=0)
    {
        if(temp1==0)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter name of customer: ");
            name = inputL.nextLine();
            cust.setName(name);

            System.out.print("\nEnter cnic of customer: ");
            cnic = inputL.nextLine();
            cust.setCnic(cnic);

            System.out.print("\nEnter age of customer: ");
            age = inputI.nextInt();
            cust.setAge(age);
            Balance(age);
            System.out.printf("\nAccount no. is: %d\n",temp1);
            System.out.printf("\nBalance of customer is: %lf\n\n",cust.getBalance(temp1));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("\nTo create a new account enter 1 or enter anything else for Transaction: ");
            temp2 = inputI.nextInt();

            if(temp2==1)
            {
                System.out.print("\nEnter name of customer: ");
                name = inputL.nextLine();
                cust.setName(name);

                System.out.print("\nEnter cnic of customer: ");
                cnic = inputL.nextLine();
                cust.setCnic(cnic);

                System.out.print("\nEnter age of customer: ");
                age = inputI.nextInt();
                cust.setAge(age);
                Balance(age);

                System.out.printf("\nAccount no. is: %d\n",temp1);
                System.out.printf("\nBalance of customer is: %lf\n\n",cust.getBalance(temp1));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("\n\nFor Deposit: 1\nFor Widthraw: 2: \n Enter Anything else to exit: ");
                check = inputI.nextInt();

                if(check==1)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\nEnter the number of account: ");
                    numb = inputI.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("\nEnter the amount: ");
                    dep = inputI.nextInt();

                    Deposit(numb,dep);
                }
                else if(check==2)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\nEnter the number of account: ");
                    numb = inputI.nextInt();

                    System.out.print("\nEnter the amount: ");
                    with = inputI.nextInt();
                    Withdraw(numb,with);
                }
            }
        }

            System.out.print("\nEnter 0 to terminate program or enter anything else to continue: ");
            temp = inputI.nextInt();
            temp1++;
    }/*End of While Loop */
}/*End of Main Method */

public static void Balance(int age)
{
    Account give = new Account();

    if(age>35)
    {
        give.setBalance(0);
    }
    else if(age>30 && age<35)
    {
        give.setBalance(10000);
    }
    else if(age>25 && age<=30)
    {
        give.setBalance(25000);
    }
    else if(age>=20 && age<=25)
    {
        give.setBalance(50000);
    }
    else
        System.out.print("\nAge limit is greater than 20\n");
}

public static void Deposit(int num, double amount)
{
    Account show = new Account();

    double tempBal = 0;
    double bonus;

    tempBal = show.getBalance(num);
    System.out.printf("\n\nCurrent balance is: %lf\n",tempBal);

    bonus = (amount/100)*5;
    amount = amount + bonus;
    tempBal = tempBal + amount;

    System.out.printf("New balance is: %lf\n\n",tempBal);
    show.setSpecificBalance(num,tempBal);
}

public static void Withdraw(int num, double amount)
{
    Account show = new Account();

    double tempBal = 0;
    double tax;

    tempBal = show.getBalance(num);
    System.out.printf("\n\nCurrent balance is: %lf\n",tempBal);

    tax = (amount/100)*10;
    amount = amount + tax;
    tempBal = tempBal - amount;

    System.out.printf("New balance is: %lf\n\n",tempBal);
    show.setSpecificBalance(num,tempBal);
}
    }
```

Please! Help just a little bit :(

Comment: I dnt think the code compile successful

Comment: yes brother thats the problem :(
it keeps giving the execption in thread main error
whenever i try to print something from the Arraylist it gives this error

Comment: As the exception states, you try to access `Balance` index 0, when it is empty. You cannot do it.

Comment: `getBalance` is trying to access an index that doesn't exist. You should use a debugger to step through your program and see what exactly is being passed in, and why.

Comment: any solution,... am a newbie.. dont know much..

Comment: I downvoted because of the comment above this.

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Answer (score 3):

You have not added any element on the arrayList `Balance` and trying to get the balance for the customer in below line :

```
   System.out.printf("\nBalance of customer is: %lf\n\n",cust.getBalance(temp1));
```

Call `getBalance` method of class Account to get the balance, method as below :

```
public double getBalance(int num)//Balance
{
    return Balance.get(num);
}
```

`getBalance` method get the element from the arrayList `Balance` but its empty so throw exception

Comment: still,.. i tried removing this statement,.. and it compiled succesfuly
but when i tried to make a deposit this thing happened again,....

Comment: can u passed exception trace, seems more error exist @user3384923

Comment: same with tempBal = show.getBalance(num); @user3384923 in deposit method

Comment: @user3384923 First add the customers detail in the list,then deposit .. whatever action you want to do

Comment: wlc @user3384923 dear